# Get attribute value/id from attribute text/label

Tags: attributes, filterable-attributes

I've a requirement to show attribute labels in URL to filter products. I'm able to generate Url with attribute labels. Now all I've to do is convert attribute label to attribute id/value (ex: 1,2), so that code behind the scene works as it is (based on attribute value/id).

Within `apply()` function of `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php` I'm getting attribute label in `$filter = $request->getParam($this->_requestVar);` (ex: Blue).

**How I can convert this attribute label to attribute id** (say for green it's 2), so that I can pass it to  `$this->_getResource()->applyFilterToCollection($this, $filter);` and backend functionality will work as it is?
I've tried `$filter->getId()`, `$filter->getValue()` but it doesn't work.

**Is it possible to get attribute value/id from attribute label?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Get attribute value/id from attribute text/label:

```
$attr = 'your_attribute';
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attr);
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    echo $color_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId("Purple");
}
```

Comment: This will get the ID of the attribute by it's code, not the ID of the attribute option by it's label :)

Comment: Check my updated code

Comment: Nice, very few lines of code

Comment: @Manashvibirla: How I can make `$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("color");` dynamic? Sometimes I will sent attribute labels from Color section, sometimes from Manufacturer, etc.

Comment: check updated ans

Answer (score 5):

There's not really a simple method to call that does that but this should do the trick

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'color');

$values = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
    ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('tsv.value', 'Bleu')
    ->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(), false)
    ->addFieldToSelect('option_id');
$values->getSelect()->limit(1);

var_dump($values->getFirstItem()->getId());
```

Note that the value has to be exactly the same as the label, so including capital letters etc.

Answer (score 3):

Get attribute option value

```
 getOptionvalue('your attribute code like color','your attribute label like blue');

    function getOptionvalue($arg_attribute, $arg_value) 
        {
            $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);

            foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option )
            {

                if($arg_value == $option['label'])
                {

                    unset($attribute);
                    return $option['value'] ; 
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is it possible to get $arg_attribute dynamically there because $arg_value will be changing( ex: sometimes it will come form color section, sometimes from Manufacturer).

Comment: Yes, call function getOptionvalue('color',blue); or getOptionvalue('manufacture','some value');

Comment: Looping through all options is not a good idea - especially if you have a lot of them.